# How select the default value when loading edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, simple-form, rails-i18n, i18n-gem

`customer_gender` is a array of array.

I want to select the current value on edit form
But it didn't work.

I think the problem is the gender's value is not a number but  a string,

How to solve this problem if the value is a string

```
customer_gender= [
['男', male],
['女', female]
]

= simple_form_for(@customer) do |f|
  .form-inputs
    - customer_gender = Customer::GENDER.collect do  |gender|
      - t(gender)
    = f.input :gender,label: t("gender"),as: :select, |
     :collection => customer_gender, |
     :include_blank => false, :selected => @customer.gender


irb(main):003:0> cols(Customer)
[
    [ 0] "id", ...
    [11] "gender",
]
```

If I   have to put numbers  in `gender` column,

How could I apply the i18n to convert 1->male, 2->female ?

Comment: Are you sure @customer has the gender attribute defined?

Answer (score 0):

Can't your transfer the `.gender` value to an integer using the [`.to_i`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i) method?

```
= simple_form_for(@customer) do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :gender, label: t("gender"), as: :select, |
     :collection => @genders, |
     :include_blank => false, :selected => @customer.gender.to_i
```

Comment: but the value is string type, "male, female" how could it be parse to integer?

Comment: Apologies - I thought you had used 0 / 1 to denote gender. The other language confused me, too - let me make an update for you

Comment: HI, Thanks for your reply,If I   have to put numbers  in `gender` column,
How could I apply the i18n to convert 1->male, 2->female ? to show the user the "male" instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

add to the model

```
def gender_txt
  ["Not Telling", "Male", "Female"][self.gender - 1]
end
 and in view 
 <%= f.select :gender,  User::GENDER_TYPES, 'data-bind' => 'value: user.gender', selected: @user.gender_txt  %>
```

this will show the corresponding text for integer gender column.